# Open & Write to Password Protected Directory

Tags: php, text, password-protection

I have a password protected directory I want to write to a text file in PHP. `cURL` is probably what it'll take, but I'm trying `fopen` right now:

```
$filename = "example.txt"; 
$file     = "https://user:pass@example.com/pass-protected-folder/" . $filename;

$fh = fopen( $file, 'w' );
fwrite( $fh, "Testing 1, 2, 3.." );
fclose( $fh );
```

Which does not work; no errors but no file gets written either.

What should I do to make `fopen` work and/or if `cURL` is a better option?

Comment: you cannot write to https. perhaps, you are trying to access example.com through FTP?

Comment: Do you want to write a file on an external Server? I would use `ssh` or `scp` for that (since, i guess apache, wont let you write over http/s) : libssh extension (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php) or in php `phpseclib' ( http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ ).

Comment: The file is on the same server. Does FTP:// work with fopen?

Comment: If the file is on the same server, you have to use the relative or absolute path of the file, ie. `/var/www/pass-protected-folder/`

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP and HTTPS Protocol won't let you create Files, 
there are PUT and DELETE but they rely on an Implementation.

The Password Protection is only for Requests through the Webserver.

If the File is located on the same server,
you could use the realtive or absolute path to the file.

For Files on an external Server you could use ssh or scp for that (since, i guess apache, wont let you write over http/s) : libssh extension (php.net/manual/en/ref.ssh2.php) or in php `phpseclib' ( phpseclib.sourceforge.net ).  If you don't mind security, you could also use FTP.

libssh Example:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect($myssh['host'], $myssh['port']);
ssh2_auth_password(
  $connection,
  $myssh['username'],
  $myssh['password']
);
$localfile = $myssh['localpath'].$file;
$remotefile = $myssh['remotepath'].$file;
ssh2_scp_send(
  $connection,
  $localfile,
  $remotefile, 0644
);
```